# $(window).height() not working in iPad fullscreen web app

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc, mobile-safari

I'm working on a web application that is nicely displayed in mobile Safari for iPad.

It eventually plays well when a shortcut is saved to the springboard, having put together the right metatags for displaying a springboard icon, splash screen and so on.

Unfortunately the app uses `$(window).width()` and `$(window).height()` and often (not always, and no, I cannot say when, I'm going crazy about that) the `$(window).height()` invocation returns 0.

I have to know the size for setting images width and height dynamically according to the viewport size and orientation. The application also use jQuery-ui and jQGrid and, when the height evaluates to 0, they both break.

The jq-ui dialogs displayed on top of the screen instead of in the middle, and the tables are not displaying correctly either.

Comment: are you using `$(document).ready(...)`, as [described here](http://www.learningjquery.com/2006/09/introducing-document-ready), to ensure that your script doesn't run until the DOM has finished loading?  If you're not doing this (or something equivalent to it), this could be the cause of your intermittent "zero-height" issues.

Comment: This question is too vague to answer with any decisiveness.

Answer (score 5):

A possible workaround is:

```
height = window.innerHeight ? window.innerHeight : $(window).height()
```

Found here: http://bugs.jquery.com/ticket/6724

Answer (score 1):

It happens that it was not an iPad issue! After searching and searching with no result, I decided to investigate about the http requests and responses issued from the iPad and performed by asp.net: it turned out that asp.net replied with content-type set to "application/xhtml+xml" instead of "text/html" and the reason was in a bug in "mobile.browser" file taken from http://mdbf.codeplex.com that sets for iPad application/xhtml+xml as preferredMimeType!
After reset it to the correct type all works well.
I'm replying here just in case anyone could incur in the same issue.
btw, mdbf is no longer supported.

Answer (score 0):

It's because of the viewport. On a regular screen, it's a basic X by Y coordinate plane. On touch screen, think of the viewport a small piece of paper that you move around ontop of a large piece of paper (the website). Here's a blurb from a post that might help:

> Mobile Safari uses a viewport to show you websites. Imagine a book in front of you. Take a piece of paper, cut a 320×416 square in it, and lay it over the book. To read the book, move the paper around and position the hole over the words you want to see. This is exactly what Mobile Safari’s viewport is doing. When you flick and scroll, you’re moving the viewport around while the website behind it stays static.

Because of this issue, you may have trouble obtaining the values you need. Below is a link to that post. Hopefully this will shed some light on positioning in regards to touch screen applications

http://doctyper.com/archives/200808/fixed-positioning-on-mobile-safari/

Additionally, Lee is correct that you need to make sure that you're document is ready.

Comment: yes I use $(document).ready. Notice that the same app works well in Safari Mobile, the problems raise when saving a bookmark to the springboard and viewing the application in fullscreen mode.

Answer (score 0):

Try checking width & height after a short delay - eg: setTmeout(300).